# Python code optimization, list comprehension, lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

Please help. I have these *for* loops:

```
        path1 = None
        for key, value in items:
            if key.func1() == a and value == b:
                path1 = key.func()
                break

        if path1 is None:
            return False
```

```
        for banana in bananas:
            found_match = False
            for key, value in items:
                path2 = key.func()
                if key == banana[0] and value == banana[1] and path1 in path2
                    found_match = True
                    break

            if not found_match:
               ...
```

Both inner *for* loops look similar, but the second one has the `path1 in path2` condition extra.

Is there a way to write this better? Maybe with a helper function?
How would this look using list comprehension or lambda func?
Thank you for any help, I am new to this.

Comment: You haven't given us any idea what these objects are. Is *items* (for example) a list of 2-tuples? Could be many things. Without knowing what you're working with it's not possible to tell you how your code could be improved

Comment: @DarkKnight My bad. Bananas and items are dictionaries with string keys and values. String variables: a, b, path1 & 2, key, value.

Comment: If *items* is a dictionary with string keys, what are you hoping *key.func()* will achieve?

Comment: @DarkKnight *items* are just flattened dictionaries. 
(They use the FlatDict, which is a dict object that allows for key/value pair mapping of nested dictionaries.)
For example:  I have *a* = "pillow", *b* = "white", so I look through the flattened list *items* and find "House.bed.pillow":"white", key has split() to get just the "pillow" and if value is "white", then *key.func()* gets the path to the key - "House.bed." 
Then *bananas* is a dict of other *a* and *b*, ie "pillow": "white", but this time they have to have to be in the same path as *path1* - "House.bed" to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By one of your comments, I assume items and bananas are something like this

```
a = "apple"
b = "berry"

itemsdict   = {"a": "b", "c": "d", "apple": "berry", "e": "f"}
bananasdict = {"a": "b", "apple": "berry", "c": "d"}

items   = itemsdict.items()
bananas = bananasdict.items()
```

With a helper function, I made something like this

```
def find (thedict, x, y):
    for key, value in thedict:
        if key == x and value == y:
            return key.func()
    return None

path1 = find(items, a, b) 
if path1 is None:
    return False

found_match = False 
for bkey, bvalue in bananas:
    path2 = find(items, bkey, bvalue)
    if path2 is not None:
        if path2 in path1:
            found_match = True
            break

if not found_match:
    ...
```

And you asked for a list comprehension version, this would be kinda straight forward like this

```
path1 = [k.func() for k, v in items if k == a and v == b] or None
# path1 is now a list containing the result of k.func()

if path1 is None:
    return False

found_match = [True for bk, bv in bananas for k, v in items if k == bk and v == bv and k.func() in path1][0]
# same as aboth, result would be [True], so to get the bool value access it with [0]

if not found_match:
    ...
```

But I think you mistook list comprehension for what it is. As far as I understood, list comprehension is for creating lists or dictionaries, not work through existing data.

And for a lambda version, or more overall, you could use the `filter()` method

```
lamb1 = lambda pair: pair[0] == a and pair[1] == b
lamb2 = lambda pair: pair[0] == a and pair[1] == b and pair[0].func() in path1

def filterfunc1(pair):
    key, value = pair
    if key == a and value == b:
        return True
    return False

def filterfunc2(pair):
    key, value = pair
    if key == a and value == b and key.func() in path1:
        return True
    return False

foundpair1 = dict(filter(filterfunc1, items)) # turn it in a dict containing the matching pairs

# there is no other generic way, known to me, to access a dict without knowing the key name, other than iteration
# also it just contains one item...
path1 = None
for k, v in foundpair1.items():
    path1 = k.func()
if path1 is None:
    return False

foundpair2 = dict(filter(lamb2, bananas))
if not foundpair2: # an empty dict equates to False
    ...
```

So here you can use the `lamb1, lamb2` lambda functions or `filterfunc1, filterfunc2` functions interchangeably.
Or put the lambda function in the `filter()` call directly to make it more compact

```
foundpair1 = dict(filter(lambda pair: pair[0] == a and pair[1] == b, items))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed simplify your code and avoid duplicating the inner loop logic by using a helper function and list comprehensions.

```
def find_match(key, value, path1, items):
    for k, v in items:
        path2 = k.func()
        if k == key and v == value and path1 in path2:
            return True
    return False

def main_logic(a, b, items, bananas):
    path1 = None
    for key, value in items:
        if key == a and value == b:
            path1 = key.func()
            break

    if path1 is None:
        return False

    for banana in bananas:
        found_match = find_match(banana[0], banana[1], path1, items)
        if not found_match:
            # Your logic when there's no match
            ...

# Usage
items = [...]  # Your list of items
bananas = [...]  # Your list of bananas
a = ...
b = ...
result = main_logic(a, b, items, bananas)
```

1. We define a find_match function to encapsulate the logic of finding
   a match within the items list based on the provided key, value, and
   path1.
2. The main_logic function is responsible for handling your main logic.
   It first finds path1 using a loop, and then for each banana, it uses
   the find_match function to check for a match.

Comment: Where are you using list comprehensions?

Comment: How do you know what *items* and *bananas* are? What do you think the first argument to *main_logic()* might be?